# Query to find a customer which has the most orders by value?

Tags: mysql, query

[image: my database model]

I am tasked with finding the customer in the database with the most placed orders by value. I was thinking about tackling this problem like this:

```
select ime,priimek, count(stranka_idstranka), sum(cena) as vrednost_racunov from racun rc, stranka s, cenik
where s.idstranka = rc.stranka_idstranka
group by idstranka
having vrednost_racunov = (select max(cena) from (select sum(cena)
from cenik
inner join zdravilo_cenik on cenik.idcenik = zdravilo_cenik.cenik_idcenik
inner join zdravilo on zdravilo.idzdravilo = zdravilo_cenik.idzdravilo_cenik
inner join racun_zdravilo on racun_zdravilo.id_racun_zdravilo  = zdravilo.idzdravilo
inner join racun on racun.idracun = racun_zdravilo.racun_idracun where datum_izdaje = "2020-03-02" and izdan_racun = 0;) temp)
order by vrednost_racunov;
```

but I didt get what I wanted. To clarify some translation issues:

- Cenik = Price list
- Zdravilo= Medicine
- Stranka= Customer
- Recept = Prescription
- Račun = Receipt, and the attribute `izdan_racun` (`tiny int`) means if the medicine sold was a prescription, then `izdan_racun = 0`, which means no receipt was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY customer
    ORDER BY ct DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Since you said *a* customer, I did not code for two customers with the same metric.

I don't know where "by value" fits in.  Maybe `SUM(value)` instead of `COUNT(*)`?

I leave it to you to fill in the FROM and JOINs.